# Ruby Gemfile gem has different behavior than 'require' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using the Matrix library in Ruby, and when I use it in `irb`, it works fine:

```
2.1.5 :001 > require 'matrix'
 => true 
2.1.5 :002 > a=Matrix.build(3,3) { |row,col| row==col ? 0 : 1}
 => Matrix[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
```

But when I use it from Gemfile, the behavior is different:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)
2.1.5 :001 > a=Matrix.build(3,3) { |row,col| row==col ? 0 : 1 }
NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for Matrix:Module
```

I inspected this a bit, and I noticed the `require` behavior loads a class, while Gemfile loads a module:

Require:

```
2.1.5 :003 > Matrix.class
 => Class 
2.1.5 :004 > Matrix.constants
 => [:EigenvalueDecomposition, :LUPDecomposition, :SELECTORS, :ConversionHelper, :CoercionHelper, :Scalar, :ErrDimensionMismatch, :ErrNotRegular, :ErrOperationNotDefined, :ErrOperationNotImplemented]
```

Gemfile:

```
2.1.5 :002 > Matrix.class
 => Module 
2.1.5 :003 > Matrix.constants
 => [:VERSION]
```

How should I include this in my Rails project? I can use `require` somewhere, but I'd really rather load it as a dependency from Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're installing the matrix 'gem' http://rubygems.org/gems/matrix in your gemfile. The matrix class is part of stdlib so you should not need to install a gem for it: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html. You do need to require it to use it however.

TL/DR: Remove gem 'matrix' from your Gemfile and just use require 'matrix' to use the stdlib matrix implementation rather than the seemingly empty 'matrix' gem Module.

Comment: Oh this is great. I didn't realize there's a matrix "gem"! I'm used to using the Gemfile to handle dependencies. I think I'll add a require statement in an initializer or model. Do you know the best practice for doing so? I really only need it for two methods.

Answer (score 1):

> Ruby Gemfile gem has different behavior than 'require' gem

Yes, that's because they *are two different things*. Adding a gem to your Gemfile does not replace the need to `require` classes, it only informs the `bundler` that this gem is needed to run your program. See [here](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html) for more information about Gemfile and Bundler.

Comment: Thanks! I use Gemfile for all my dependencies, I'm under the impression that it automatically requires anything I mark in it unless I specify `require: false`